# AJAX - OnSubmit Problem

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I am fairly new to AJAX so please forgive me.

I have to forms - the fist one works but the second does not and I don't know why. The fist html form does not have submit button but the second does. They both use the same javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
 } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","server_script.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

From 1:

```
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="0001">0001</option>
```

0002

**Person info will be listed here.**

From 2:

```
<form onsubmit="showUser(this.foo.value)">
<input type="foo" >
<input type="submit" >
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first one your ajax is firing `onchange`, as such there is no default behaviour that is going to interfere with that.

On the second form you are using the `onsubmit` event, which has the default behaviour of posting back the form to the server. So you have to `return false` or `preventdefault` on that event to allow your ajax code to complete. The easiest fix would be to simply add a return false:

```
<form onsubmit="showUser(this.foo.value); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `showUser` return false, otherwise the form will be submitted by the browser by the usual means.